# How to show NuGet package dependencies?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. In a **.NET Framework** project, I want to show which packages an installed package depends on. How can this be done?

If I create a .NET Core project, this information seems easily available under the "Dependencies" item under Project in the Solution Explorer pane (one can expand and browse the hierarchy).

In a .NET project however, there exists a "References" instead of "Dependencies", but it cannot be expanded in the same way.

Comment: Nothing like that is available for Visual Studio when you are not using an SDK style project. Possibly you could use [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer). It does not show you the full tree but shows dependencies for each NuGet package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with **Matt**, what you want for now is not supported in `.net framework` projects. This feature is available only for new SDK format projects like `.net core` and `.net standard` projects. See [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591109/10910450) here.

And as I know, there doesn't exist extensions which supports this behavior. So I'm afraid the answer is negative, we can't use `nuget dependency tree` in `.net framework` projects cause both VS IDE itself and VS extensions don't support this.

If you do need this feature, I recommend you can post your feature request in [Developer Community Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)
(Our User Voice forum).  If it get enough votes, the Product Team would consider it seriously. Thanks for your help to make VS better :)

Answer (score -3):

You can bifurcate by this way:

[image]

- Right click on your project.
- Select Manage Nuget Packages option.
- Select "Installed" tab which shows you your added NuGet packages.

Comment: Doesn't that just display the direct dependencies? In my case, I want to show the dependencies of the direct dependencies.