# NuGet dependency tree

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Is there a way to get tree of dependencies for project/solution with any level of depth?

I checked several questions on StackOverflow already. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653715/view-nuget-package-dependency-hierarchy) is the closest to what I need. But it is recommended there to use `NuGet.Core` package, the package is marked as deprecated and anyway code snippents cannon be built.

Preferencies:

- API that possible to use in C# code
- Original (not third-party) tools / APIs

Comment: Another answer in that question mentions this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuget-tree have you try it ?

Comment: There are other options in that question that you mentioned, please try them before openning a new question.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Thank you for suggestion. Yes, I tried this NPM package. It does shows dependencies with depth but it shows them linear, without any visualization like a graph. Also, API that can be used in C# code (so I could put some extra logic) would be prefered, but that's not a deal-breaker.

Comment: Please include the criteria that you just mentioned into the original question.