# Nuget package installed even if it is not included in project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I have `npgsql` and `npgsql.entityframeworkcore.postgresql` nuget packges being installed every time when I build my solution although they are not included in my project.

They are creating me problem because there are some ambiguous extension methods so I would like to remove them.

The question is, are they maybe installed as dependency by some other library that I use and is there way that I could check that?

Comment: Are they dependencies of some other nuget package? Which nuget packages do you explicitly depend on in your project file, and what's the project SDK you're using?

Comment: Well, that was the question, how can I check if they are dependecy of some other package?

Comment: If you're in Visual Studio, open the Solution Explorer and keep expanding the Dependencies section of your application. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653715/view-nuget-package-dependency-hierarchy

Comment: Search it in Solution Explore ( Ctrl+; ). You will be able to find it even it is a transitive dependency of another package and you will know who referencing it.