# No references to a .dll file anywhere in the project - but file appears after the project is built

Tags: .net, .csproj.in

I've very new to this so have a question to something I don't really understand - I would like to update a .dll and I don't know how

I have a csproj, when I build this project it produces a bin folder - and in that bin folder is a .dll I would like to update

```
System.Drawing.Common.dll
```

This is the file structure where it turns up;

**project/bin/Debug/net6.0/System.Drawing.Common.dll**

There are no references to this .dll file, no strings, nothing in any json file, and nothing in the csproj file .. for example I would expect something like;

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="5.0.1" />
```

And again nothing in the gitlab repo itself .. only once it's built does this file appear

So how do I go about updating this .dll? How can I tell what version the file currently is and steps to updating?

I hope my question makes sense

Comment: Is this a dependency of a NuGet package that the project is using?  There could be multiple steps in that dependency chain.

Comment: Yeah I think it must be a dependency of a NuGet package .. is there a way I can tell what that chain would be?

This package has been automatically flagged as needing to be updated but finding it difficult to know where it's from

Comment: This might work, depending on project versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653715/view-nuget-package-dependency-hierarchy